# Apache Thrift Struct for better readability

Tags: java, refactoring, thrift, code-readability

I just started working with thrift and created following thrift interface.

```
map<string, map<string, string>> getInformationByIds(1: set<string> Ids)
```

As you can see, the return type is a `map of maps`. I want to know wether I can improve the readability by creating a custom thrift structure. Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have trouble relating this to readability only, I can give a generic advice that might also solve that question for you.

### Use a `struct` as return value

Service methods are (currently) designed in a way most programming languages<sup>1)</sup> use the concept of a callable function: Although it allows for  handing over **0-N arguments**, you are still limited to a maximum of **one return value** only <sup>2)</sup>:

```
RETVAL  function( ARG1, ARG2, ..., ARGN) throws (...)
```

So using as `struct` as a return value in your service methods turns out to be a quite clever approach. In fact, it solves four problems at once:

- not limited to 1 return value anymore: add as many fields as you need
- extendable: you can add more fields in the future without breaking it
- readability: separating method and retval gives you cleaner code
- reusability: easily possible to use the same return structure for multiple methods

How cool is that?

---

<sub>1) e.g. Golang is a notable exception.</sub>

<sub>2) We are not counting exceptions here, only normal data.</sub>